# Change the number of consecutive frequent ssh login before temporary blocking the user login

Tags: ssh, security, login

my server currently would temporarily refuse a user to login for certain amount of time (maybe ~20min) if the user consecutively frequent ssh login for 3 times. Can I change this behaviour (say relaxed the definition of frequent maybe from 'within 5 sec' to 'within 10 sec'; or increase the # of consecutive login from 3 to 5)? Thanks.

Added: Ah.. now I think the problem was not with the ssh. I just tried on another newly installed server. consecutive successful login won't block the user. I have no sudo permission on the server I mentioned above. Now I suspect this behaviour may cause by the firewall in the system. Thanks everyone's comments.

ADDED 2: Ah... after some searches. I think the server is using /sbin/iptables to do it as I can see the iptables program is there even though I don't have permission to list the rules. Thanks everyone, special thank to jaume and Mark!

Comment: There's not really enough information here for anyone to help you out -- you need to list your server's OS & Version, and whether any 3rd-party firewall application is installed (and what it is, if there is one).

Comment: If you mean that users can't login for 20 min after 3 failed attempts, yes, you can change this behavior. [If you want to know _how_, please provide more information, as _PJC_ requested: OS and version, SSH version and firewall information (if it is `iptables`, please provide  `iptables -S`.]

Comment: @jaume, no. not changing the consecutive failed login attempt information. The ssh will block the user for certain amount of time when after 3 consecutive frequent successful login.

Comment: What are you using for blocking them? fail2ban?

Comment: @Mark, I got no idea on what is used to introduce this behaviour on the server. It's annoying and I was thinking may possibly ssh configures that so I asked. But it seems I was wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @Mark, I checked the server, there is not /etc/fail2ban or similar file or directory so seems the system is not using this one. Do you have any idea how I can check what cause this behaviour? Thanks.

Comment: @Kenneth - sorry, no idea

Answer (score 0):

I think the program you're looking for is [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/). In order to change the number of attempts before blocking you'd need to edit `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf` and change 'max retries' for ssh - you can get more information on fail2ban configuration [here](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8#General_settings) on fail2ban's website

Comment: I think the op is saying that they are *currently* blocking incorrect logins, but they want to change the metrics on what triggers a block. Sadly they don't tell us what they're using to currently do the block...